# Recommended ROS Version for Kuka Youbot

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, ros-groovy, youbot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

which Version of ROS would you recommend for the KUKA Youbot.

The manufacturer ships it with ROS Fuerte, which seems to be quite old. I have seen that there are packages for ROS Groovy and also for ROS Hydro. Is it save and recommended to update?

I am currently testing ROS Hydro on a youbot running Ubuntu 12.04 and will report my findings.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128981/recommended-ros-version-for-kuka-youbot/) by [Jabro](https://answers.ros.org/users/9246/jabro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Hydro ...................................................

---

Originally posted by [praman2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/12421/praman2s/) with karma: 31 on 2014-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jabro](https://answers.ros.org/users/9246/jabro/) on 2014-02-25**:
could you elaborate this a bit more? Are there many people already using ROS Hydro? Have you made the best experiences using ROS Hydro?

**Comment by [praman2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/12421/praman2s/) on 2014-02-25**:
There was a release and all the repos are moving to hydro-devel.
You can also find the driver wrapper in hydro :
http://www.youbot-store.com/youbot-developers/software/ros/ros-hydro-wrapper-for-kuka-youbot-api

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-04-16**:
There are [Hydro packages](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/hydro.html?q=youbot). Wiki pages of the most of packages weren't created (now I have done), which can be why it was a bit hard to find ROS packages.